# Determine concurrency based on a key (such as an id) with RabbitMQ

Tags: concurrency, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We are building a web application using RabbitMQ and Spring's listener-containers to produce concurrency as follows:

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrency="10">
      <rabbit:listener ref="FooService" method="handleFoo" queue-names="fooQueue"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="fooQueue" pattern="foo.handle"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
```

I want the listeners to process messages concurrently ( e.g. 10 threads for this example ), but I don't want them to concurrently process messages with same data. For example if I am sending id's of Foo objects, I only want different Foo objects to be concurrently processed, but same Foo objects should be sequentially processed.

I have gone over the exchange and queue types of RabbitMQ but could not figure out to do this with any of them.

One way I can think of is to create multiple queues with different patterns such as `foo.handle.1`, `foo.handle.2` and so forth. And then hash the id of the Foo objects to these patterns. But doing this for every type of queue we have and managing all of it can get out of hands quite easily.

Is there a mechanism to accomplish this with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike JMS, RabbitMQ (or AMQP itself) has no concept of a message selector - you can't pull selective messages from a queue.

The only solution with RabbitMQ is a separate queue for each type and a single consumer on each queue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you elaborate on `separate queue for each type`. I have only one type `Foo` and there are many `Foo` objects with different ids. Should I hash the ids like I proposed in the question?

Comment: Sorry - I misread - yes; you would need to hash the id to determine which queue to send it to.

Comment: Thanks again, one last thing, can rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange <https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange> with a binding pattern `foo.handle.#` and routing key `foo.handle.<foo-id>` help me with this kind of problem? I would still need to create 10 queues, but the producers wouldn't have to worry about the hash function, right?

Comment: Yes, that would work but the binding is not as you describe - see the readme. I am not familiar with the exchange but it seems all the bindings would be simply `"1"` for even distribution across the queues.